# What is a good replacement for "I've lost count of the times..."?

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests

Suppose I'm talking about a repetitive action someone else has repetitively done in the past.

I've used the expression *"I've lost count of the times..."* earlier on. I'm looking for a similar idiomatic phrase.

Answer (score 0):

**If I had a [nickel | dime] for every time...**

Example:  If I had a nickel for every time John came in late, I'd be a millionaire.

Answer (score 0):

***for the millionth time***

Cambridge Dictionary:

> **[millionth](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/millionth)**
>
> *informal* They're showing "High Noon" on TV **for the millionth time** (= having already shown it a lot of times).

Answer (score 0):

[Umpteen](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/umpteen), meaning a large number. "You've done it umpteen times, isn't that enough?". The term suggests some number between thirteen and nineteen.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few. They're wordy, but effective:

- **I can't keep track of how many times you've done this.**
- **I don't know how many times this has happened.**
- **Is there no end to the number of times you'll do this?**
- **Your capacity for doing this seems to be endless.**

Answer (score -1):

Frequent offender

Ad nauseam

If you are being sassy, ironic or humorous you may want to employ litotes.

Are you trying to express the offender's frequency, your personal disdain for or both?